# How to map an array or object from Api Gateway integration request mapping template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have **POST** method in API Gateway that accepts the data passed from body params.

[image]

From the API Gateway, I managed to get the userName and uuid, but I'm having an error getting the traveledCities. How can I map an array or an object passed from body params

[image]

I'm getting an error from $inputRoot.traveledCities line 5

Comment: Have you tried just surronding it with [], like ["$inputRoot.traveledCities"] ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the template directly with the array field. Here an example:

**Request:**

```
POST apigateway/stage/resource?query=test
{
  "id": "id",
  "list": [1,2,3,4]
}
```

**Mapping:**

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "query": "$input.params('query')",
  "id": "$inputRoot.id",
  "list": $inputRoot.list
}
```